# Arrays.sort does not work in java

Tags: java, android, sorting

I am having a custom class called Company, and it has fields being latitude and longitude.
I want to sort them based on distance from current location but it does not seem to work.

I have double checked all the data, and they are correct but for a reason the sorting does not seem to work.

Code is :

```
currentCompanies=AllCompanies.sortByDistanceFromOwnLocation(currentCompanies, AppConstant.userLatitude, AppConstant.userLongitude);
```

which calls these :

```
public static Vector<Company> sortByDistanceFromOwnLocation(
            Vector<Company> locations, final double myLatitude,
            final double myLongitude) {



        Comparator comp = new Comparator<Company>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Company o, Company o2) {
                float[] result1 = new float[3];
                android.location.Location.distanceBetween(myLatitude,
                        myLongitude,
                        Double.parseDouble(o.getLatitude().trim()),
                        Double.parseDouble(o.getLongitude().trim()), 
                        result1);
                Float distance1 = result1[0];


                float[] result2 = new float[3];
                android.location.Location.distanceBetween(myLatitude,
                        myLongitude,
                        Double.parseDouble(o2.getLatitude().trim()),
                        Double.parseDouble(o2.getLongitude().trim()), 
                        result2);
                Float distance2 = result2[0];

                return distance1.compareTo(distance2);
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(locations, comp);

        return locations;
    }
```

which calls this from the Collection.class:

```
/**
 * Sorts the given list using the given comparator. The algorithm is
 * stable which means equal elements don't get reordered.
 *
 * @throws ClassCastException if any element does not implement {@code Comparable},
 *     or if {@code compareTo} throws for any pair of elements.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    T[] array = list.toArray((T[]) new Object[list.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(array, comparator);
    int i = 0;
    ListIterator<T> it = list.listIterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
        it.set(array[i++]);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT :

Ok more info on that. I am having 8 companies - lets say id from 1 to 8. I have added this log inside the compare method :

```
        System.out.println("Compare between id :" + o.getId() + " and " + o2.getId());
```

And is being called only for these id's :

```
Compare between id :2 and 1
Compare between id :3 and 2
```

Data for all the companies are :

```
12-24 17:00:51.318: I/System.out(19041): Company : 1 Latitude :37.9407699 Longitude:23.7489698
12-24 17:00:51.318: I/System.out(19041): Company : 2 Latitude :37.9407699 Longitude:23.7489698
12-24 17:00:51.318: I/System.out(19041): Company : 3 Latitude :37.9407699 Longitude:23.7489698
12-24 17:00:51.319: I/System.out(19041): Company : 4 Latitude :41,352979 Longitude:26,502281
12-24 17:00:51.319: I/System.out(19041): Company : 5 Latitude :41,352979 Longitude:26,502281
12-24 17:00:51.319: I/System.out(19041): Company : 6 Latitude :41,352979 Longitude:26,502281
12-24 17:00:51.319: I/System.out(19041): Company : 7 Latitude :37.0861346 Longitude:25.1608451
12-24 17:00:51.319: I/System.out(19041): Company : 8 Latitude :38.078994 Longitude:23.727481
```

Result of the comparison between id 1 and 2 and 2 and 3 is 0 => equal (which is correct). The others are not compared at all.

Why is that?

Comment: You can use a tool called debugger and check the problem in your `Comparator#compare` method.

Comment: What is the second param in the `Double.parseDouble` function used for? The Java documentation has no `Double.parseDouble` method accepting two parameters. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

Comment: "it does not seem to work" is not a good description of the difference between what you expect and what you actually see.

Comment: @JonSkeet it does not change anything in the order of the elements in the array, even though the distances are not sorted

Comment: Aside from anything else, it looks like `Company.getLatitude()` and `Company.getLongitude()` should be changed to return `double` rather than `String`...

Comment: A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would help then. Something that shows sample input and output data. (And do you really need to use `Vector<E>` rather than `ArrayList<E>`?)

Comment: I do not know what your results are, so I cannot figure out what the problem is, but either way your code has lots of duplicated code. You should have one method for calculating distance for a single company, and just compare the results. Also, the part parses the latitude/longitude should also be moved to its own method; in your code it is repeated 4 times!

Comment: @mbomb007 there is a single parameter being used in `Double#parseDouble` in this code. Read it again.

Comment: Ah. Edited for clarity.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss ok, can you please me help me on that - I am new to Java and I am trying to understand this code : The compare method, is called only for the first two entries of the array, I have added Logs inside that but they are called just twice.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you see my edit?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza can you see my edit, please?

Comment: It's hardly a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, is it? It doesn't have any information about the latitude/longitude of the companies being compared, not the result of the comparison. We have no indication of there actually *being* 8 companies in `AllCompanies`... basically there's very little in there to help us. There's a *lot* you can do to diagnose this, but at the moment we can't help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok I added my data - I cannot understand why the compare method is not being called for all my companies.

Comment: Looking at the log lines, I suspect that you're catching an exception somewhere and ignoring it... I've added an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we can see the *string* values for the latitude and longitude, I suspect I know the problem. `Double.parseDouble` will throw an exception for a string like this: `41,352979`.

My guess is that somewhere you're catching `Exception` and effectively ignoring it. That exception is being thrown during the `sort` method, when the comparator tries to parse the invalid value.

Things to fix:

- Your data: we don't know where you're getting the latitude and longitude from, but it looks like it's not "clean" in terms of number representations
- Your data model: `Company.getLatitude` and `Company.getLongitude` should be `double` values already; it shouldn't be up to the user to trim strings and parse them
- Your exception handling: assuming I'm right, you shouldn't be ignoring exceptions the way you are
- Your diagnostics: if an exception *does* occur, you should always be logging it, whatever you do afterwards

Comment: Thanks mate, that was it. Changing , to . fixed that.

Comment: @ghostrider: I hope that's not *all* you did - see my answer for things I think you should be looking at changing.